# jMeter no FTP request option

Tags: linux, ftp, jmeter

I am learning about jMeter, following [this course](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_ftp_test_plan.htm). I want to add an FTP request, but there is no such thing in the menu.
There is no `Add → Config Element → FTP Request Defaults` and no `Add → Sampler → FTP Request`. But I have for example `Add → Sampler → HTTP Request`.

I am using jMeter 2.13.20161028 on Debian GNU/Linux 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install a separate package in order to add FTP protocol support to your JMeter installation: [jmeter-ftp](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/jmeter-ftp), you can do it like:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt get install jmeter-ftp
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the plugin up.

---

It seems that your Debian distribution comes with a little bit outdated JMeter version (~3 years old) so I would recommend considering upgrading to the latest version ([JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3) as of now), the most recent JMeter versions normally come with new features, bug fixes and performance improvements.

JMeter is pure Java application so there is no need to use package manager, given you have [Java 8](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-debian-8) you should be able to just download the [latest JMeter tarball](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi), unpack it and run.